# How do I know which field is selected in access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform from a table on a form. I need to know which field is selected. First I select a field on a sunform and then I click a button which calls a sunroutine. That subroutine has to know which field is selected.
I tried Screen.ActiveControl.Name but it's value was the button's name.

Thanks

Comment: Define "selected".

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth, this is not duplicate of mentioned question. `ActiveControl` cannot be used for identification of field, when focus already moved to the button.

Comment: @SergeyS. then he needs to be clear in the question that he wants the previously selected control. That can be achieved by writing the control (or control name) to a variable on the `LostFocus` event for every control. I thought he wanted the active control of the subform while the button was on the main form, and then the duplicate is entirely valid.

Comment: `Me.mySubformControl.Form.ActiveControl` might work. (And if it does, it is a duplicate :) )

Comment: I wanted the proviously selected control. Sorry make you confused.